# Required and StringLength are ignored by ASP.NET MVC5 - EF6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-6

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with a asp.net mvc 5 and entity framework 6. I am following an online course and the steps the author is doing, is creating 2 classes with properties, then marking properties as [Required] and assign [StringLength(255)] to some other string properties. The modifications work on one class but not on the other.

This is the code for the 2 classes:

**The one that's working:**

```
 public class Genre
    {
        public byte Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**The one that's not working:**

```
public class Gig
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public ApplicationUser Artist { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Venue { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    }
```

I ran migration first time before adding the attributes, and the CreateTables.cs migration looks like this:

```
 public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Genres",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Byte(nullable: false),
                    Name = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Gigs",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    DateTime = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    Venue = c.String(),
                    Artist_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                    Genre_Id = c.Byte(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.Artist_Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Genres", t => t.Genre_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Artist_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Genre_Id);

    }
```

Then I added the attributes to my code, and added a new migration, When I run add migration, the generated code in the migration is like this:

```
  public override void Up()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Gigs", "Artist_Id", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Gigs", "Genre_Id", "dbo.Genres");
            DropIndex("dbo.Gigs", new[] { "Artist_Id" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Gigs", new[] { "Genre_Id" });
            AlterColumn("dbo.Genres", "Name", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 255));
            AlterColumn("dbo.Gigs", "Venue", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 255));
            AlterColumn("dbo.Gigs", "Artist_Id", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
            AlterColumn("dbo.Gigs", "Genre_Id", c => c.Byte(nullable: false));
            CreateIndex("dbo.Gigs", "Artist_Id");
            CreateIndex("dbo.Gigs", "Genre_Id");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Gigs", "Artist_Id", "dbo.AspNetUsers", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Gigs", "Genre_Id", "dbo.Genres", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
        }
```

However, the generated T-SQL code to create the table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Gigs] (
[Id]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[DateTime]  DATETIME       NOT NULL,
[Venue]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Artist_Id] NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
[Genre_Id]  TINYINT        NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Gigs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Gigs_dbo.AspNetUsers_Artist_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Artist_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]),


   CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Gigs_dbo.Genres_Genre_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Genre_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Genres] ([Id])
);
```

However, the generated TSQL for the other table, was right:

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Genres] (
    [Id]   TINYINT        NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Genres] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Why the T-SQL is not reflecting the modifications by the migration for the 1st table? Knowing that I added the migration and executed update-database, and could see the changes for one table (Genre), but not the other.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That SQL is going to create the table, the migration will run an `ALTER TABLE...` statement to make the changes you added later on.

Comment: @DavidG so why did it update one table and not the other? How do I get my table to be updated?

Comment: Have you actually applied the migration yet?

Comment: I did, as I said in my question. I ran add-migration migrationname, then update-database

Comment: So the `AlterColumn` command would have changed the table definition of your table. How did you generate the SQL above?

Comment: The SQL is generated when you execute update-database, which is going to read your migration.cs code.. not sure why the TSQL is different from the actual .cs code

Comment: There must be more than that generated. The migration you show doesn't include a `CREATE TABLE` component at all.

Comment: @DavidG please, see the updated post.

Comment: Yes, so that SQL comes from the first migration, the other migration should run some different SQL to make the changes.

Comment: Have you tried to specify your last migration explicitly using `-TargetMigration` flag?

Comment: @DavidG so what should I do in this case?

Comment: @RomanKoliada no, I am just going along the video course I have, and he just did as I did. he didn't mention anything about -TargetMigration. I'll search how to use it

Comment: Shouldn't the update-database look at the last migration added?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_5

Comment: I think the last migration will update the SQL statement, like it did with the other table.

Comment: You don't need to specify the target migration, it will try to run them all by default.

Comment: The migration doesn't change the SQL statement, it will run a *completely new one* that runs *after* the first one.

Comment: @DavidG it did change the SQL statement actually. For my Genre class, it created the T-SQL statement first time with no "NOT NULL". When I added the attributed and updated the database using update-database, the T-SQL has completely changed. Check my updated post again.

Comment: Am not sure if visual studio 2017 acts differently, or EF6 is just different.

Comment: No, that's not possible. It will just have been a new table or something like that. A migration is just that, an attempt to *migrate* your data structure to a new format.

Comment: @DavidG How's it not possible? This is what am seeing. I don't see any update table in T-SQL, it's just Create Table, with the not null added as needed. Same thing is not happening for the other table.

Comment: @brittany Did you checked the actual schema in the DB via SSMS? Or you just judging by sql in the output?

Comment: I am checking in server explorer > data connections > Default connection (myproj) > Tables. Do I need to do it in another way? @RomanKoliada

Comment: @RomanKoliada I don't have SSMS installed

Comment: @RomanKoliada I took the project to an environment with VS 2015, and it worked just fine, it's a problem with VS 2017

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem, neither `StringLength` nor `MaxLength` Data Annotations didn't helped me much. It seems I'm trying to use same online course, which initially for MSVS2015, but I'm using latest MSVS2017.

What I've tried so far:

- Setting length as is and the change only it in migration
- Setting specific migration version with `Update-Database -TargetMigration Migration`
- Setting all the migrations from scratch with `Update-Database -TargetMigration 0 | Update-Database -Force`
- Recreating database (Deleting database in SQL Server Object Explorer)

And after all SQL definition still contains initial MAX constraint, as well as table definition.

Part of migration

```
AlterColumn("dbo.Genres", "Name", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 255));
AlterColumn("dbo.Gigs", "Venue", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 255));
AlterColumn("dbo.Gigs", "Artist_Id", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
```

Database definition after all migrations

```
[Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
...
[Venue]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Artist_Id] NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
```